# Setting gmaps to false, can't update geocoding location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm using the great gem [gmaps4rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) to put a Google Map on my Ruby on Rails site. I'm following [this page](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Model-Customization) on the wiki and trying to control when the calculated latitude and longitude should be updated, by setting the `gmaps` field to false. I can't seem to get it to work.

In my User model, I've got this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   acts_as_gmappable

   attr_accessible :latitude, :longitude, :address, :gmaps

   def gmaps4rails_address
      address
   end
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here. I'm changing the `address` field to something new directly in the database using SQLite Database Browser, setting `latitude` and `longitude` to 0, and I've tried setting `gmaps` to false, f, 0, null (not sure what false is in SQLite)... then loading the map again by refreshing the page. It always shows the marker at 0,0..

I thought all I had to do was define a `boolean` called `gmaps`, and when it is set to false, upon loading the map, it should recalculate the lat/long by geocoding the address. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [the test here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/test/dummy/spec/models/user_spec.rb), line 72.

The coordinates aren't refreshed on map load, this is part of the validation process of an `acts_as_gmappable` model.

```
model_instance.update_attributes({ :sec_address => "new address", 
                                   :gmaps       => false })
```

Comment: Like I said, something simple :) Thanks a lot!